# Add translate3d for each element in menu with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, translate3d

I need to do an `translate3d` for my menu,

I need to create animation like this menu in this site in mobile ( https://www.micai.aristidebenoist.com/ ).

You can see `translate3d`  how can work, its show as slow animation

i try more code but i cannot do like it

My code :

```js
$('.menu-trigger').on('click', function() {
  $('#menu-slide-menu li').each(function() {
    $('#menu-slide-menu li').css('transform', 'translate3d(0%, 0px, 0px)');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-trigger">Menu</div>
<ul id="menu-slide-menu">
  <li class="element">bla bla</li>
  <li class="element">bla bla</li>
  <li class="element">bla bla</li>
  <li class="element">bla bla</li>
</ul>
```

How can do it!

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve with the `li`?

Comment: this menu in css is opacity = 0, when click to nav bar  i need to show this menu like site i posted it

Comment: the ul is `hidden` , when click to div `menu-trigger`, i need to show all menu element like menu here ( https://www.micai.aristidebenoist.com/ ) in mobile

Comment: @Eddie are you understand me ?